# What are these lettered blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Today I entered the Debug world type for Minecraft to check out all the new blocks in 1.9.  Oddly enough I found an interesting block I had never seen before even after experimenting with 1.9.  They looked odd and had letters on them like this:[image]

What are these lettered blocks, and can I attain them?

Comment: Never heard of a debug mode world. How can I enter it?

Comment: @angussidney seems like ANOTHER good question. I thought that we ran out of good minecraft questions.

Comment: @angussidney, click "create new world" go to "more world options" Hold shift on "world type" and click it five times starting at default.  Lol, answering a question on a question.

Comment: @Jason_ http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258906/what-is-a-debug-world-and-how-can-i-create-one

Comment: That's the one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They were used to test end structures, S stands for Save, L stands for Load, C stands for Corner, D stands for Data, but you can't obtain them. However, you can place them in a world with cheats are enabled by using the command `/setblock x y z structure_block`. A good reason to use them is the fact that they emit 15 light (as bright as sun) and their toughness is very high.

You can see the [Wiki Post here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Structure_Block).

Comment: I've read that they can save / load structures but can't verify atm.