# What is a debug world and how can I create one?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently heard of a world type called 'Debug Mode'.

- What is it?
- How can I enter or create this world?

Answer (score 7):

### What is it?

Debug mode is a world type which generates a world containing all block data types in all states. It is very useful for developers and resource pack creators.

It contains a total of 5274 unique block types and states. The gamemode is set to spectator by deafult. Breaking or placing blocks is impossible.

### How can I enter or create this world?

On the 'create world' screen, hold <kbd>↑ Shift</kbd> and left click until 'Debug mode' appears. It should be after the customised world type.

Note that debug mode is only available in 1.8 and above.

[image: clicking the world type button]

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Debug_mode)

Comment: @Daenyth done, edited